# On a Mac, how to rename all files ending with a question mark?

Tags: macos, file-management, find-and-replace

I have some files that are like:

```
123.mp3?
```

I need to rename them to 123.mp3

How can I do this to all the files in a given folder?

I'm on a Mac

Answer (score 3):

You could use `zsh` and `zmv` to easily achieve this with these commands :

> % zsh
>
> % autoload -Uz zmv
>
> % cd /path/to/folder
>
> % zmv '(*).(*)?' '$1.$2'

You can, of course, change both patterns.

Answer (score 2):

There's always AppleScript, but if you want an app to handle it for you, there's [A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) and [Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/).

Answer (score 2):

Run the AppleScript `/Library/Scripts/Finder Scripts/Replace Text in Item Names.scpt` and it will prompt you for a replacement and perform it on the items in the frontmost Finder window.

(An easy way to run scripts like this is to use the Script menu; open AppleScript Utility (in `/Applications/AppleScript`) to enable it.)

Answer (score 1):

There are rename actions in Automator. I'd try those. Or use a decent shell.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [NameChanger](https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/), it's donateware and pretty simple.